# Integrate DocuSign with Wrike

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to integrate **DocuSign** with **wrike** as we are already using **wrike** for tasks, projects management and work flow.

Our documents are available on wrike and we want to use **DocuSign** for digital signature service.

I explored the documentation and did not found any relevant material except request a sign (It's a long process and we don't need it).

Is there any api for automatic digital signature?

Consider the following work flow:

- Our marketing team created a task to distribute 100 chips stands to
  different shops.
- This request directly goes to brand manager.
- If brand manager approve the request then it goes to our director.
- Now we want the director level approval with digital signature.

How can we use DocuSign with wrike?

Answer (score 1):

Re: Can you use DocuSign with [wrike](https://www.wrike.com/)? Yes.

If you want your director to approve/sign a document with a digital signature, use [Envelopes: create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) and request a digital signature.

Are you sure that you need a digital signature? Most internal approval processes work fine with electronic signatures.

Depending on what you want to do, some of DocuSign's new [digital signature capabilities](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/resource_event_files/DocuSign_Standards_Based_Signatures_Data_Sheet.pdf), announced in June 2016 are still in preview mode.  If you're interesting in early access, you can email apihelp@docusign.com

Depending on wrike's APIs, there are usually many ways to integrate with it.